# Doctrine 2: How to update one-to-one bidirectional

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, associations

I have problem with updating one-to-one bidirectional association.

User Entity

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="test_user")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="login", type="string", length=32, nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $login;


    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Points", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $points;

     ...


    /**
     * Set points
     */
     public function setPoints(array $points)
     {
        $this->points = new Points($points);
        $this->points->setUser($this);

        return $this;
     }

    /**
     * Get points
     */
    public function getPoints()
    {
        return $this->points;
    }

}
```

Points Entity

```
/**
 * Points
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="test_user_points")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Points {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",  nullable=false)
     */
    private $points;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="period", type="string", length=24)
     */
     private $period;


    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="points")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;





    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(array $params = array())
    {
        $hydrator = new MyHydrator();
        $hydrator->hydrate($params, $this);
    }


    ...

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function setUser(User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }


}
```

Class **MyHydrator** is converting from array(first param) to object(second param). It is very important and I have to use it.

My save function looks like this:

```
public function save(array $data)
{
    ...

    // This is how my input data looks

    $data = array(
        'login' => 'Test',
        array(
            'points' => 999,
            'period' => 'monthly'
        )
    );

    if ($userExists) {
        // UPDATE
        $hydrator = new MyHydrator();
        $hydrator->hydrate($data, $userExists);
        $this->em->persist($userExists);
        $this->em->flush();

    } else {
        // INSERT
        $user = new User($data);
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

Inserting to database works perfect, but when I try to update record I get error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4' for key 'UNIQ_DAD93D6EA76ED395'
```

**4** is a value of **user_id** column in **points** table

How can I edit existing record without error about duplicate id?

Answer (score 0):

It's old but since I encoutered a similar issue, I resolved it this way :
in User

```
public function setPoints($points)
{
    if ($this->points !== null) {
        $this->points->setUser(null);
    }
    $this->points = $points;
    $points->setUser($this);
}
```